# SSRS Same dataset for more parameters

Tags: reporting-services

My report has 5 parameters (string, multivalue, not nullable) and all of them are obtained from the same dataset at the same time because they don't depend on each other;
All of them have default values;
When I enter the preview only one of them displays the field filled, the other 4 don't but they all have the correct data as a selectable option.

The XML structure of each parameter is the same, the dataset is a common one but only one (not the first in the parameter box, nor the first or the last in alphabetical order) is correctly filled. I can't figure out the problem.

The query I execute to retrieve the parameters if the following:

```
SELECT s.[MaterialId]
    ,s.[WO]
    ,s.[WorkCenter]
    ,s.[SrcLocSign]
    ,s.[ConfLocsign]
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

and my parameters are MaterialId, WO, etc

Here's a picture of the parameter box as the preview started.

[image: example]

**EDIT**

This is the result of my stored procedure:

```
[MaterialId]    [WO]        [WorkCenter]    [SrcLocSign]    [ConfLocsign]
14100478        40204211    P01             P01             CW1-FG
14337544        40221636    P24             P24             NULL
14486209        40229237    NULL            NULL            NULL
NULL            40229239    NULL            NULL            NULL
```

As you can see, no row in "WO" column contains a null values and I'm sure this is the reason why is the only one correctly displayed.
The stored is pretty heavy to execute for each parameter and I can't see any solution but:
- create a ##table with the sp result
- a column for each parameter with 'WHERE x IS NOT NULL' condition

Pros: I avoid to execute an heavy view/procedure 5 times.
Cons: My problem now is how to execute the ##table filler at first

Comment: are they cascading parameters? I.E. each child dependent on it's parent? How do you assign default values for each?

Comment: no, they don't depends on each other and they are evaluated all at once with the same query;
I set available values and default values by selecting the column name in the configuration form

Comment: Have you tried populating the parameters from 5 different datasets? TBH that's a strange way to do it.

Comment: The query I am using to retrieve the parameters is pretty heavy (about 30 seconds and lots of full outer joins), I tried to get all of 5 at once

Comment: Can you confirm in ssms that a value is returned for all the parameters

Comment: Just saw your edit.. why not make null value as blank and make parameters allowed for blank?

Comment: Also.. I'm pretty sure if you used a single transaction on your dataset.. you will be able to reuse your temp tables in your stored procedure.. for multiple datasets. could be the way to go.

Comment: Why not make blank instead of null? Because then I'd have many blank options in the combo box which I can't filter;

Regarding the temp: yea, I was trying to, but I'm struggling in executing the stored that fills the temptable before the other 5 queries.
I added an internal parameter (called "flag" which is an integer 1 or 0). Its value is returned by the filling-stored procedure but then the following queries cannot see the temptable. I'll update you if it worked, thanks.